# Use Emulated Scrollwheel Instead of Real One X11

Tags: x11, mouse, scrolling

So I've got this Kensington trackball that ships with a pretty horrible scrollwheel/touchring doohicky, and only two physical buttons. I'd like to disable the touchscroll entirely, enable 3 button emulation and use the emulated third button as the emulated wheel activator.

When I do

```
Section "InputClass"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 0 0"
    Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
EndSection
```

The touchscroll is disabled, but so is the logical X11 YAxis buttons (4 & 5) so I can only scroll horizontally.

Anyone know if its possible to preference emulated scrolling over the wheel itself?

Edit:

Made some progress. X11 manual mentions the "ZAxisMapping" which changes the buttons that initiate a scroll event (I think).

```
Section "InputClass"
    Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
    Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 0 0"
    Option "YAxisMapping" "11 12"
    Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "11 12 6 7"
EndSection
```

Making the arguments match what I've mapped to the emulated scrollwheel seems to work in urxvt, but not in any gtk apps. (I assume gtk doesn't utilize the ZAxisMapping option from xorg.conf but rather continues to listen for the disabled 4 and 5 butons.)

Comment: Which model is your mouse?

Comment: Kensington Orbit - it's pretty good except for the scrolltouch/touchscroll monstrosity